# Python: how to assign a name of a list variable to a class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, graph, subclassing

Basically, I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
lst = [['B', 'A'], ['C', 'B'], ['D', 'B'], ['E','C D'] ......]
```

Where `t[0]` supposed to be a subclass of `t[1]` (from which it inherits).

I need to write a script that creates empty classes with names matching `lst` and then checks whenever a `t[i-1]` is a subclass of `t[i]`:

```
if issubclass(B, A)== True:
   print('Yes')
```

So far, I understand how to begin and how to finish the script but I'm completely unaware  how to assign a name from a list so that it would be possible to use `issubclass`.
Maybe there are other ways of creating classes and tracing their inheritance?

I've just started learning classes and OOP today, so it's  more than possible that I missed something crucial while dealing with this problem.

Comment: Note: `[1, 2, ...]` is a list, and `(1, 2, ...)` is a tuple. `lst` is a list of lists.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is advanced metaprogramming. It's not the sort of thing you see in ordinary everyday Python code. If this is for an assignment, that's fine. If this is a personal challenge, it's a great question. But don't start thinking that the code you propose (and the code in my answer) is typical or idiomatic. What you've asked for is advanced and somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way we define classes is with the `class` keyword, naturally.

```
class B(A):
    some_variable = 100
```

Effectively, we're *constructing* a new type in the Python runtime. And, in fact, types have their own constructor in Python; it's called [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) and we can call it directly. The above declaration is roughly equivalent to

```
B = type('B', ('A',), { 'some_variable': 100 })
```

And now the type names are strings. There's just one more piece of the puzzle we'll need. We want to take and assign it to the name `B`, using a string so we can do so with names that aren't known in advance. Assuming you want to do this at module-scope, we can use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), which returns a dictionary of the current module's top-level variables, which we can freely modify to add more variables. So we can do

```
globals()['B'] = type('B', ('A',), { 'some_variable': 100 })
```

Now, let's put those pieces together and write a script that uses the `lst` list you suggested.

```
lst = [['B', 'A'], ['C', 'B'], ['D', 'B'], ['E','C D']]

# Iterate over the list.
for class_name, superclass_names in lst:
    # Here, we're going to lookup all of the superclass names in the
    # current global scope. It's a little more complicated than that,
    # since we also want to *create* any names that don't exist (like
    # 'A' in your example) when we find them.
    superclasses = []
    for superclass_name in superclass_names.split(' '):
        # If the name doesn't exist, create it and assume its
        # supertype is object, the root of Python's type hierarchy.
        if superclass_name not in globals():
            globals()[superclass_name] = type(superclass_name, (object,), {})
        # Get the class, whether it's the one we just made or one that
        # already exists.
        superclasses.append(globals()[superclass_name])
    # Now we construct the new class. The first argument to type() is
    # the class name, the second is all of the superclasses (it must
    # be a tuple, not a list, according to the documentation, so we
    # convert it), and finally the contents. Since you just want the
    # classes themselves, I'll assume the contents are meant to be
    # empty. You can easily change that as needed.
    globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, tuple(superclasses), {})

# Now let's see that everything is defined correctly. __mro__ is a
# complicated concept, but the basic idea is that it should give us E,
# followed by all of its subclasses in a reasonable order (for some
# definition of reasonable).
print(E.__mro__)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTBjtMwEL3nK0baQ1IU5cINiQPLrmAvCAkuaFVVjjNtwzqeyHa2RIhvX57tbBsWyCmd2m/evDcv4xyOYl8/PRXGB3pL9/fldVlT@a7c1nRfvo/v1/n9ZvV@W9ble7opt9uiuKK7wE4FJnlkR@HIZHofmmIvjrRR3u@sGrgmP43sLgVPvSV0fVMQniv6yA6HTlw6poP09kBByIg8TCMpY0j2CfuCQmcU1BcQPTnHNtDBSKsMeS0jNyBYelKgFYJhGgQdtAyj6TVod7iuIoYK9YLie6sZVNDXC50UAMHllXaM869I2XnpHS9RJ7YMxD8wNFWmf3jmAhEjuVkmh38V@vGGTke2EXnf29iYhyadvkwFVNiwTdWo4AvVIuJLIRuPUUJVUrnJYub@d1mwdKsT9meWNeVJqA@YpSMATRE5@NXt1CTMI@qepP3OGvcinhMJ0YzPaXUgbDp07LEDTh/n5ozR7/8ib3EVA2R3fLWiG59z@f7FvS0kiV2qF/WaqoXZpqafvzYr@h84JLbpcB1lxy@HGSNh1MUmg79PMG1QHQou1aKjKxhloFQ3Z938Zba1X40aR7Zd9X/6m2UjPskpNtVifXCTzgwtnzLLhr4e42I4UFLuAEvy3qXJN7BhQTmPRVmDlAoGaBet@mdUsFQVzB4w7QLSYrkpTNjJOrmiUmhrUlqL65b0RZBOdGKiQi8WIUYezmETi8TD0QD54yJhqdF@zgzFBlzDVF9SmhCDrHaO0yWxC7@YBc/mkeHWXYkhlq1cY0EWxJeXPLbPEDyMYW7oGzpoJJmV70FCI9WHbCiwIDN33GUHL079Y8fW65UEqtY6LotWZDMNx33yvLRhyIFURPXgRMfQA58XCOqwowYUd7vByW6XfCqu/vgIYUbNIxxop7wXLcbQ1Hes4vGEDwv9USbT0aF/ZJo83daA2YsxcgJGOz/bjyzD/vZZXGROETbZi1WticveIQxV@r7IwMBIZPvocbx@ObppitH1NlS3zUJ@Uzw9/QY)

Comment: That is a thinker, thanks for the thorough explanation. If I understand correctly, classes that we get from this code are only to be called directly. Is it possible to create a new list containing these classes or to transform an old one, so that they could be referred by the list? For now I've failed to accomplish that because adding superclasses and class_names to a list returns a list of strings.

Comment: Sure, you can pretty easily modify my above code to accumulate a list of classes. Everywhere I do `type(...)`, just append the result of that to a list somewhere. Then you've got your list of new types

Comment: Thanks again! As always, it's only after changing (at least, trying to change) a code for numerous times, I began to understand the general logics that is used to build it.